# Clickable button which pulls user input to create a new url

Tags: android, url, button

My code is as follows:

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Get My Image button */
final String baseUrl = "http://examplewebsite.com/";    
Button viewimagebutton = null
viewimagebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imagegetter);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ 

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pixelw);
                EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pixelh);
                        EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pixels);
        String url = baseUrl + editText1.getText().toString() + "/"
                + editText2.getText().toString() + "/"
                + editText3.getText().toString() + "/";
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    }});
    // Do something in response to button
}
```

However on the line

```
 viewimagebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imagegetter);
```

I get quite an error which has a few syntax suggestions. I have followed what people have said here, but I am at a loss right now. If you need more info feel free to ask

Comment: Of course it's possible.  But how you append those values to the URL depends entirely on what your code is currently doing.  How do you capture the values, and how do you direct the user to the URL?  Show some code which demonstrates what you currently have and indicate how you need to pass those values from Point A to Point B.

Answer (score 1):

Totally possible. You haven't stated how the user inputs the 3 inputs. I've assumed 3 different `EditText` fields you've defined earlier.

If so it would look something like this.

```
final String baseUrl = "http://examplewebsite.com/";    
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String url = baseUrl + editText1.getText().toString() + "/"
                + editText2.getText().toString() + "/"
                + editText3.getText().toString() + "/"
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    }});
```

When the user clicks on the `button`, they'll be directed to the url which is made up of the base url + the inputs of the 3 `EditText` fields.

Comment: The user inputs them into some edit text fields, so from what you have said this should work, I will let you know.

Comment: Right, ive tried inputting your code and modifying to my needs. I have a few errors from that. "editText1 cannot be resolved" then "editText2 cannot be resolved, Line breakpoint:MainActivity [Line: 32] - onClick(View)" and finally "editText3 cannot be resolved". What would be going on here, the editText names are correct. Are there other things I need to input and not word for word as such?

Comment: You need to make sure all three are in your xml, and you've initialised them with the ids in your xml, like `EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.whatever_you_called_it);`

Comment: ok I am having some major issues, when I run the app and click the Get My Image button it just closes. When I add in the `button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {` I get tonnes of syntax errors followed by button cannot be resolved and OnClickListener cannot be resolved by a type.

Answer (score 1):

As Ken pointed out (unfortunately I don't have enough rep to reply yet) it's just concatenating strings.

If you think the parameter list may grow in the future, an iterative handle may be better and pass the params in as a List or array. Whatever you feel most appropriate.

But also consider using the URL object if this is for the purpose of a web-service. It allows some controlled manipulation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html

Apologies if it is irrelevant, I used it for communication with a web-service during my project so it's all I've had experience with so far.

N.B. And also whack some validation on them fields if you're directly reading them in from the onClick action! :)

Comment: You need to link your GLOBAL editTextX references to the actual Views that they should be referencing.

E.g:

In the main class body: 
    `private EditText mForename = null;`

then within onCreate()

    `mForenameView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_forename);`

R.id.et_forename corresponds to the ID you gave the element/view with your XML layout file.

If you've already done this, something may be compromising your R file (an error somewhere in the xml layout file).

IT KILLS ME NOT BEING ABLE TO COMMENT!!!

Comment: Don't worry, sometimes wish I had someone here who also knew how to code. I'm only into this for the first time today. So anything I ask will probably sound stupid =/

Comment: Nono, I know everyone has to start somewhere. I recommend you fire through the official Android Tutorial. It helped quite a bit staring my project. It was the first time I had experienced android too, but I have a fair grasp on Java so that helped. I can't comment directly to other peoples posts so I was afraid you would miss that.

Link to tutorial:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Some of it is quite complex, outdated or not needed. And it is forever changing. I do not like it at all but it did help a wee bit when getting started. 

Good luck!
regards,
Scoch

Comment: Per your error below, your button needs to reference an element/view too. Everything that you want to manipulate or read from within the UI, you need to create a reference to it within your java code.

e.g. :

`Button myButton = null;`

then within onCreate:

`myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_my_button);`

replace btn_my_button with the ID you gave your button.

If OnClickListener isn't being resolved it probably hasn't been imported. Use the error tooltip to resolve or organize imports (eclipse shortcut is ctrl+shift+o).

Comment: ok, nearly there, I have one error now, the code I have in place is 'Button viewimagebutton = null
    viewimagebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imagegetter);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {' and the error is Multpile Markers at this line, followed by a series of syntax errors, @N3ViT you have been a massive help so far

Comment: Can you try cleaning and rebuilding the project, then seeing if the tooltip updates?

The error tooltip should provide useful info like this:

http://i.imgur.com/94q6jZU.png

Apologies for the lapse in replies BTW. I am currently 5 hours behind GMT and I am only really available evening times. I'll be back in the UK from the 29th

Comment: Its Ok, I got it working, just trying to create a textview which shows the user their screen resolution now. Thanks for your help. Its been much appreciated.